# Why can’t we use multinomial theorem here?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, multinomial-theorem

We have $10$ white, $9$ green and $7$ black balls. All balls are identical except for colour. While the solution for selecting number of ways in which one or more balls can be selected from these already exists which is $(1+10)(1+9)(1+7) - 1$, I want to know why we cannot use this method:

$ x_1$ = number  of  white  balls  chosen

$ x_2$ = number  of  green  balls  chosen

$ x_3$ = number  of  black  balls  chosen

$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq 26 $$

$$x_1,x_2,x_3 \geq 0\ \mathrm{and}\ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + k = 26,   k \geq 0 $$

Answer = Coefficient  of  $x^{26}$ in  $$(x^0 + x^1+\cdots+x^{10})(x^0+\cdots+x^9)(x^0+\cdots+x^7)(x^0 + \cdots+x^{25}) $$
This is giving me the wrong answer and I don’t know why.

Comment: I don't want to click that link to download something that I don't know the size of, because I'm on mobile right now, and have to ration my megabytes somewhat. So I have no idea what technique you're talking about. That being said, I can guess what the answer is anyways: multinomial coefficients (including binomial coefficients) are most commonly used to count combinations when the total number of chosen things is known and fixed.

Comment: @Arthur It is an image I took from my iPhone. I take each colour to be a variable, alongwith an auxiliary variable for the inequality. x1 + x2 + x3 + k = 26

Comment: You can use generating functions.  You could also use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.  However, both of these techniques involve much more work than the calculation you showed in your question.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your questions rather than posting an image since images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you wanna find out the no. of ways of selecting one or more balls. This answer, $$(1+10)(1+9)(1+7)−1=879 $$
is perfectly correct for this.

But, note that, when you find the coefficient of $x^{26}$ in

$$(x^0+x^1.......x^{10})(x^0+..........x^9)(x^0+.........+x^7)$$

what you find is the no. of ways of selecting **ALL** the balls and not at least one!

To find out the no. of ways of selecting at least one ball, you'll have to find the sum of the coefficients of $x^1,x^2,...x^{26}$, which in this case becomes (taking $x=1$)

$$(1+10)(1+9)(1+7)−1$$

Note that I've put $-1$ since $x^0$'s coefficient has to be excluded from the sum.

Comment: The equation has been corrected. Someone put an equal to.

Comment: I changed that, but apparently my edit wasn't accepted exactly

Comment: I hope my solution helped you

Comment: OMG stop putting the equal to!

Comment: Please look at the question again.